# Deleting unwanted packages

Tags: package

Is there any way to delete unwanted packages?

I don't see delete option, there is only edit option.

I have created many packages and now I need to delete those.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the package name, and then click "Delete" on the package detail page. You can't delete a managed package, however.

Comment: There is no delete option.

Comment: Assuming you have the permission to modify/delete packages, and the package is unmanaged, you should be able to. If not, you'll probably need to contact technical support. I'm not aware of any other reason why you wouldn't be able to delete the package.

Comment: I just ran into this again... You have to deprecate all existing versions (uploads) before you can delete the package. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the package, The package detailed page will be opened. In That page you will find EDIT, DELETE and UPLOAD. Just click on delete button!

Answer (score 0):

If any package can not be deleted, you can depreciate it. And then It will allow you to delete the package.